# Android project working for everyone but me.

Tags: android

I pulled a project from git and this happens when i try to run it.

**This exact branch is working for other people**, but not for me.

I think something in my settings isn't allowing me to have so many dependencies, yet it works for others...

Here are my two errors:

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

and

Error:Execution failed for task ':UserApp:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Did you happen to click the link you provided and read that article?

Comment: See [an explanation here](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2014/10/30/android-and-the-dex-64k-methods-limit/). An app's dex file can't have more than 64K methods. The solution described there is to use multi-dex instead of only one.